# How will I do This? XSLT.. I can not change header level

Tags: html, xml, xslt

```
<xsl:template name="entries" match="entries">
   <xsl:with-param name="ictr" select="1"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/heads/headers/@id=$ictr/header" mode="header"/>

 <xsl:template match="header" mode="header">
 <th style="width:100px">
       <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
 </th>
  </xsl:template>

            <heads>
                <headers id="1">
                    <header num="Programs / Activity / Projects">a1</header>
                    <header num="Key Program Code(s)">a2</header>
                </headers>

                 <headers id="2">
                    <header num="Programs / Activity / Projects">a1</header>
                    <header num="Key Program Code(s)">a2</header>
                </headers>
            </heads>
```

I want to change header level from parameter... anyone can help?
ictr is my parameter, which I will fill it trough a loop, but I don't know how to do it with this ex.

Comment: This question is not clear, i.e. incomplete. Show your entire XSLT stylesheet, the input XML and the output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath expression you are using probably does not do what you expect.

```
/heads/headers/@id=$ictr/header
```

You might be looking for something like this instead?

```
/heads/headers/header[@id=$ictr]
```

Selecting a `header` element whose `id` attribute value is equal to the value of `$ictr`.

Comment: How could I set value of variable inside for each and assign it on match template?